# CSS Refactoring Best Practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

we are working on a large web application with Rails for quite a while and produced a lot of css for our templates. Stylesheet definitions are organised in a bunch of css files that have grown with the project. As people are not always as disciplined as they should be, it seems to me that a lot of definitions have become deprecated and useless.

Is there an (semi-)automatic way to get rid of this stuff? How do you identify useless css in your project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Dust-Me Selector](http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/)s plugin for Firefox or the <strike>[CSS redundancy checker](http://services.immike.net/css-checker/)</strike>.

Both are great tools that I use often and they save you hours of searching and deleting.

Another tool worth making note of also is the [CSS Tidy](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/) open source project. This minifies your CSS, especially useful in these cases when you have a huge site with a huge CSS file :)

---

I believe the sourcecode for the CSS Redundancy checker can be found [here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/11074). Ran it through the JSLint plugin at jsFiddle.net but gave me some errors, saved it for everyone [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/2H5cJ/).

Comment: the second link you mentioned here doesn't load for me. I'd be interested to see it if you can find the correct link.

Comment: Hmm, seems it's gone for good. That's strange. I'll see if I can find a similar tool :)

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly a 'rails' solution but you don't always need one.  I use the [Dust-Me Selectors](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5392/) firefox plugin to find unused selectors.  Works for me.

edit: kyle beat me to it

Answer (score 0):

We didn't have a particularly large CSS file (about 3500 lines) and we found it sufficient to grep the codebase for each selector. (Obviously this can be semi-automated with shell pipes, xargs and friends).

Following this process, we ended up deleting a few too many CSS styles, thanks to some of our CSS style names being dynamically generated (a bad idea in retrospect).

For more detail about our workflow and results, I co-wrote a few thousand words about our experience turning the CSS from a Rails 2.x app into an asset pipeline ready, responsive and modular Rails 4.2.x SASS setup.

[CSS Refactoring: From append-only to modular CSS](https://www.oxbridgenotes.com/articles/css_refactoring_from_append_only_to_modular_css)